# My disqus comments count isn't showing up. What's wrong?

Tags: jekyll, disqus

This is my [repo](https://github.com/Jwan622/Jwan622.github.io) and here is [my live site](http://www.iamthemangosteen.com). As you can see on my live site... the comments count never loads. It always reads Comments loading...

What is the ...#disqus_thread part doing in the a tag?

Here is my jekyll code that iterates through all posts:

```
<div class="posts">
  {% for post in paginator.posts %}
    <article class="post">
      <h1 class="post-title"><a href="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h1>

      <div class="entry">
        <span> {{ post.excerpt }} <a href="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ post.url }}" class="read-more">[...]</a> </span>
      </div>

      <span class="date front-page-date">{{ post.date | date: "%B %d, %Y" }}</span>
      <a href="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ post.url }}#disqus_thread" class="comments-count">Comments Loading...</a>
    </article>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Here is my disqus layout/partial:

```
{% if site.disqus %}
<div class="comments">
    <div id="disqus_thread"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var disqus_identifier = document.location.pathname.split("/").slice(1,5).join('');
    var disqus_shortname = '{{ site.disqus }}';

    (function() {
        var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
        dsq.src = '//' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
        (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
    })();

    </script>
    <noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the <a href="http://disqus.com/?ref_noscript">comments powered by Disqus.</a></noscript>

</div>
{% endif %}
```

And here is my disqus_count partial that is right above my closing body tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  /* * * CONFIGURATION VARIABLES: EDIT BEFORE PASTING INTO YOUR WEBPAGE * * */
  var disqus_shortname = '{{ site.disqus }}';

  /* * * DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE * * */
  (function () {
  var s = document.createElement('script'); s.async = true;
  s.type = 'text/javascript';
  s.src = '//' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/count.js';
  (document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('BODY')[0]).appendChild(s);
  }());
</script>
```

Each of my posts includes the disqus layout and so that works fine. But I am trying to show the number of comments that each post has in my jekyll index page. How do I do this? My spans do not seem to be working and in each of my disqus sections, I am using a disqus identifier which based off the url. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide a repository url ? It can help to spot you problem.

Comment: Repo Url: https://github.com/Jwan622/Jwan622.github.io

Comment: What is the #disqus_thread part doing?   <a href="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ post.url }}#disqus_thread" class="comments-count">Comments Loading...</a>

Comment: It seems to work well here. The post count is showed on index page. Have you fixed?

Comment: Yeah the problem was that the root domain was incorrect for all the disqus embeds. So I had to switch it all to the correct root of iamthemangosteen. I am unclear why they didn't show up correctly the first time. I also still don't know how to correctly use disqus_variables